# Python MNIST Digit Data Testing Failure

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, mnist

Hello I am using Python to try to read the digit data provided by MNIST into a data structure I can use to train a neural network. I am testing to ensure the data was read properly by creating an image using PIL. The image that is being created is horribly wrong, and I am not sure if it is because I am using PIL incorrectly or my data structures and methods are not right.

The format of the two data files is described here:
http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/

Here are the applicable functions:

read_image_data reads the pixel data organizing it into a list of 2D array numpy arrays

```
def read_image_data():
    fd = open("train-images.idx3-ubyte", "rb")

    images_bin_string = fd.read()

    num_images = struct.unpack(">i", images_bin_string[4:8])[0]

    image_data_bank = []

    uint32_num_bytes = 4

    current_index = 8

    num_rows = struct.unpack(">I", \
        images_bin_string[current_index:  current_index + uint32_num_bytes])[0]

    num_cols = struct.unpack(">I", \
        images_bin_string[current_index + uint32_num_bytes: \
        current_index + uint32_num_bytes * 2])[0]

    current_index += 8  


    i = 0
    while i < num_images:
        image_data = np.zeros([num_rows, num_cols])

        for j in range(num_rows - 1):
            for k in range(num_cols - 1):
                image_data[j][k] = images_bin_string[current_index  + j * k]

        current_index += num_rows * num_cols

        i += 1
        image_data_bank.append(image_data)

    return image_data_bank
```

read_label_data reads the corresponding labels into a list

```
def read_label_data():
    fd = open("train-labels.idx1-ubyte", "rb")

    images_bin_string = fd.read()

    num_images = struct.unpack(">i", images_bin_string[4:8])[0]

    image_data_bank = []

    current_index = 8

    i = 0
    while i < num_images:
        image_data_bank.append(images_bin_string[current_index])
        current_index += 1
        i += 1

    return image_data_bank
```

collect_data zips the structures together

```
def collect_data():
    print("Reading image data...")
    image_data = read_image_data()

    print("Reading label data...")
    label_data = read_label_data()

    print("Zipping data sets...")
    all_data = np.array(list(zip(image_data, label_data)))

    return all_data
```

lastly run_test uses PIL to print the pixels from the first 28x28 np structure created by read_image_data

```
def run_test(data):
    example = data[0]
    pixel_data = example[0]
    number = example[1]
    print(number)
    im = Image.fromarray(pixel_data)
    im.show()
```

When I run the script:

> Collecting data... Reading image data... Reading label data... Zipping
>   data sets... 5

[image]

I must be messing something up with the PIL library, but I do not know what.
That is a really weird looking 5. I am guessing that I went wrong somewhere in my organization of the data. The directions did say "Pixels are organized row-wise.", but I think I covered that by having my outer loop as the row loop then the inner as the column loop

**UPDATE**

I reversed the order of the row and column index in the np.arrays in read_image_data and it is making no difference.

```
image_data[k][j] = images_bin_string[current_index  + j * k]
```

[image]

**UPDATE**
Ran quick test with matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
imgplot = plt.imshow(pixel_data)
plt.show()
```

Here is what I got from matplotlib
[image]

That means it is definitely a problem with my code and not the library. The question is if it is the way I am passing the pixels to the imaging libraries or how I structured the data. If anyone can find the mistake, I would greatly appreciate.